# How to resolve the below error

Tags: oracle

```
Enter user-name: xl_dba@test
Enter password:
```

> ERROR: ORA-12528: TNS:listener: all appropriate instances are blocking new `

How to resolve that error?

Comment: this error means blocking the new connection

Answer (score 0):

This is what Oracle says:

> ORA-12528: TNS: listener: all appropriate instances are blocking new
>   connections
>
> Cause: All instances supporting the service requested by
>   the client reported that they were blocking the new connections. This
>   condition may be temporary, such as at instance startup.
>
> Action: Attempt the connection again. If error persists, then contact
>   the administrator to check the status of the instances.

Run LSNRCTL at the command prompt and bounce the listener:

```
LSNRCTL> stop
LSNRCTL> start
```

Then start the database instance - connect to SQL*Plus as SYSDBA and run

```
SQL> startup
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the Listener current status by using below command.

```
[oracle@mydb01 ~]$ lsnrctl status
```

if you are getting error in output then please start Listener.

Listener start command

```
[oracle@mydb01 ~]$ lsnrctl start
```